# How to update mat-select selection checked/unchecked based on ngModel value change?

Tags: angular, select, angular-material

I'm currently building a search form with the Material library and Angular 8, where multiple options can be selected in the mat-select dropdown option list to be displayed as chips with cancel icon in the form field. When the cancel icon of the chip is clicked, the chip will be removed from the form field. However, the correlated option in the select dropdown list is not being unchecked accordingly. Here below is my code and any help or info would be greatly appreciated.

html part:

```
<mat-form-field class="chips-select-form" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Multi Select Chips Form</mat-label>
  <mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let selectedChip of chips_selected"
              [selectable]="selectable"
              [removable]="removable"
              (removed)="remove(selectedChip)">
      {{selectedChip}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <mat-select disableOptionCentering multiple name="chipSelect"
                [formControl]="reportingForms.controls['chipSelect']"
                [(ngModel)]="chips_selected">
      <mat-option>-- None --</mat-option>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let chipOption of chipOptionList" [value]="chipOption">
        {{chipOption}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-hint>Click outside of the form when selection is done</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts part:

```
chipOptionList: any = ['All', 'NodeChip-0', 'NodeChip-1', 'NodeChip-2', 'NodeChip-3'];

remove(removedOption: string): void {
    const index = this.chips_selected.indexOf(removedOption);
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.chips_selected.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```